# how much space does a given package, and dependencies, cost?

Tags: apt, package-management

given a package name, I want  to find how much space would be freed up if the package, and its dependencies, were deleted.

As dependencies might be shared between packages, maybe the right way to put it is: How much space does a package take, including all dependencies that are only beeing used by this package

I would prefer CLI solutions, because I would use them in scripts

Comment: `apt-cache show packagename` lists, among other things, the installed size of a package and the dependencies of a package. There's also `apt-cache rdepends package` to list the packages that use that package. You might want to start there.

Comment: @saiarcot895 - post that as an answer please

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simplest and bug free way to get the space used by a program and all its dependencies is to use apt itself. Note dependencies that are not used by another program, but installed with a package, is not considered as they are not removed.
Simply

```
sudo apt-get --assume-no autoremove PACKAGENAME
```

or

```
apt-space-used-by() { sudo apt-get --assume-no autoremove $@ | grep freed | cut -d' ' -f4-5 ;}
```

usage  `apt-space-used-by PACKAGENAME`

[This](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=73098) python script looks promising  (bigpkg - find packages that require a lot of space on your system)

Comment: isn't this python script for Arch ?

Comment: we should first run "sudo apt-get --assume-no autoremove" to see if there are packages the system wants to remove anyway (independent of the package you are thinking of removing)

Comment: Is't thatv what I  answered ? You need execute 'purge' after 'remove'

Comment: I mean: run this with no PACKAGENAME, get a number
run with PACKAGENAME, get another.
subtract

Comment: you are right, and that's special case.

Answer (score 6):

- #### Simply try following command ( to get disk space freed by purge):

  ```
  echo -n | sudo apt-get purge <package> | grep "disk space will be freed"
  ```

  or

  ```
  echo -n | sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove <package> | grep "disk space will be freed"
  ```

  where replace `<package>` with your `package-name` ( example: `gimp`)

  This **will not purge package** with dependencies but **only gives how much disk space will be freed** with help of `grep`!

---

- #### **Using `dpkg --print-avail` or `apt-cache show`:**

  ```
  apt-cache show <package> | grep "Installed-Size"
  ```

  or

  ```
  dpkg --print-avail <package> | grep "Installed-Size"
  ```

  **This will display installed size of `<package>`.**

  Example:

  ```
  $ apt-cache show gimp | grep "Installed-Size"
  Installed-Size: 15024
  ```

---

- #### Sort list of installed packages by size

  ```
  dpkg-query -W -f='${Installed-Size;8}  ${Package}\n' | sort -n
  ```

  You can use more for page-wise:

  ```
  dpkg-query -W -f='${Installed-Size;8}  ${Package}\n' | sort -n | more
  ```

  Above list packages according to size acceding, you can use `tail` to list packages consuming top size as follows:

  ```
  dpkg-query -W -f='${Installed-Size;8}  ${Package}\n' | sort -n | tail
  ```

---

- #### **Using `dpigs` (from man `dpigs`):**

  > dpigs - Show which installed packages occupy the most space

  ```
   dpigs sorts the installed packages by size and outputs the largest ones. Per default dpigs displays the largest 10 packages. You can change
     this value by using the -n option (see "OPTIONS"). The information is taken from the dpkg status file with grep-status(1)
  ```

  This Can be installed by: **`sudo apt-get install debian-goodies`**
  Example of run command

  ```
  $ dpigs
  115449 wine1.6-i386
  110356 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic
  103828 libreoffice-core
  86240 fonts-horai-umefont
  74016 libreoffice-common
  72709 liboxideqtcore0
  61736 linux-headers-3.13.0-24
  60821 libpyzy-1.0-0
  59477 firefox
  59443 thunderbird
  ```

---

- #### Finding size of Unused package:-

  ```
  popularity-contest (8) - list the most popular Debian packages
  popcon-largest-unused (8) - List size of unused packages
  ```

  First run `popularity-contest` and then `popcon-largest-unused`, This will help you to find size of unused package. Visit man-pages for more information.

---

I tried my best to provide useful commands by steps.
*Hope these helps!*

Comment: What're the units of the "installed size" from dpkg/aptcache ? Like, bytes, kilobytes…?

Answer (score 2):

`apt-cache show packagename` lists, among other things, the installed size of a package and the dependencies of a package. There's also `apt-cache rdepends packagename` to list the packages that use that package.

You might want to use the latter command and `apt-cache policy packagename` to determine if a reverse-depdendency is installed.

Comment: This size does not appear to be human readable.

Comment: The `Installed-Size` is in kilobytes, whereas `Size` is in bytes. I should have mentioned that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a script](https://bitbucket.org/nicktime/deb-hogs) which does that. No machine-friendly output though.

`sudo apt-get install python-apt`

and you're ready to go.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import (absolute_import, division,
                        print_function, unicode_literals)
import apt
from apt.cache import Filter, FilteredCache

MB = 1024*1024

class InstalledFilter(Filter):
    def apply(self, pkg):
        return pkg.is_installed

def iter_base_deps(cache, package):
    deps = []
    version = package.installed
    for dep_type in ('Depends', 'PreDepends', 'Recommends'):
        deps.extend(version.get_dependencies(dep_type))
    for dep in deps:
        for base_dep in dep:
            if base_dep.name in cache:
                yield base_dep

def main():
    package_ref_count = {}
    results = []

    cache = FilteredCache(apt.Cache())
    cache.set_filter(InstalledFilter())
    for package in cache:
        for base_dep in iter_base_deps(cache, package):
            if base_dep.name in package_ref_count:
                package_ref_count[base_dep.name] += 1
            else:
                package_ref_count[base_dep.name] = 1

    for package in cache:
        base_deps_size = 0
        base_deps = []
        for base_dep in iter_base_deps(cache, package):
            if package_ref_count[base_dep.name] == 1:
                base_deps.append(base_dep)
                base_deps_size += cache[base_dep.name].installed.installed_size
        total_size = package.installed.installed_size + base_deps_size
        results.append((total_size, package, base_deps_size, base_deps))

    for total_size, package, base_deps_size, base_deps in sorted(results, reverse=True):
        if package.name in package_ref_count:
            continue
        if total_size < MB:
            break
        self_size = package.installed.installed_size
        base_dep_count = len(base_deps)
        print('{:.1f} MB  {}'.format(total_size/MB, package.name) + \
              (' with {} deps'.format(base_dep_count) if base_dep_count else ''))
        if base_dep_count:
            print('    {:.1f} MB  self'.format(self_size/MB))
            for base_dep in base_deps:
                size = cache[base_dep.name].installed.installed_size
                print('    {:.1f} MB  {}'.format(size/MB, base_dep.name))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example output:

```
72.6 MB  gthumb with 4 deps
    3.0 MB  self
    61.0 MB  libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25
    8.0 MB  gthumb-data
    0.1 MB  gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs
    0.5 MB  flex
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I want, a list of biggest package, with the size including dependencies. However the output is not complete, it accounts for less than a gigabyte. My system uses about 8gigs. Most of it has to be packages - I am sure - I hardly have any data.

Comment: @Rolf, I'm glad it was useful. Indeed, a lot of packages are not listed, that happens if a package is depended by several others.
I've tried plotting dependencies as a graph, that way user could see all the packages and all the dependencies. But it turns to a complete mess, a ball of spaghetti.
Sorry for late reply.